# Create a stratified table (pivot table) of summary statistics from a survey object

Tags: r, pivot-table, crosstab, gtsummary

I am having trouble driving the creation of summary tables with sub-levels (two levels of stratification; nesting) via gtsummary::tbl_svysummary.

I have already created the object survey::svydesign with the following variables: Gender, Country, Result, n(weighted). I managed to create a table, however I can't create an additional stratum by Gender. I have put the tabular structure I want below.

[image]

I could even generate individual tables (nesting each country by filter) and stack them. However, there are 21 countries and I would like a more rational strategy.

Please, any suggestions...

Code

```
# dataframe
df <- 
  data.frame(
    Country = c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", 
               "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3",
               "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3",
               "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"),
    Result = c("A", "B", "C", 
               "B", "C", "A",
               "C", "A", "B",
               "A", "B", "C"), 
    Gender = c("M", "M", "M",
                "W", "W", "W",
               "M", "M", "M",
               "W", "W", "W"), 
    n = c(583, 607, 1217,
          487, 1100, 820, 
          178, 304, 367,
          223,444,112))
df

# Create a weighted survey design object
df_survey <- survey::svydesign(~1,
                                data = df,
                                weights = ~n)
# Table
Table <- df_survey %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = Result,
                 percent = "row") %>% 
  add_overall(last = TRUE,
              col_label = "**n(row)**") %>%
  modify_header(label = "",
                stat_by = "**{level}**") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels() %>%
  italicize_labels()
Table
```

Comment: Could you add some data and code you've tried?

Comment: Hi, Please re-read the post. I have pasted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that gets you very close to the mocked-up table you provided. You can convert the output to flextable with `as_flex_table()` to make it aa bit more similar.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

df <- 
  tibble(
    Country = c("Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3", 
                "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3",
                "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3",
                "Country 1", "Country 2", "Country 3"),
    Result = c("A", "B", "C", 
               "B", "C", "A",
               "C", "A", "B",
               "A", "B", "C"), 
    Gender = c("M", "M", "M",
               "W", "W", "W",
               "M", "M", "M",
               "W", "W", "W"), 
    n = c(583, 607, 1217,
          487, 1100, 820, 
          178, 304, 367,
          223,444,112))

# Create a weighted survey design object
df_survey <- survey::svydesign(~1,
                               data = df,
                               weights = ~n)


df_results <-
  tibble(Country = unique(df_survey$variables$Country)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    # subset the design object within each country
    design = df_survey[df_survey$variables$Country %in% Country, ] %>% list(),
    # construct gtsummary table within each stratum
    tbl = 
      design %>%
      tbl_svysummary(by = Result,
                     percent = "row",
                     include = -Country) %>% 
      add_overall(last = TRUE,
                  col_label = "**n(row)**") %>%
      modify_header(label = "",
                    stat_by = "**{level}**") %>%
      modify_footnote(everything() ~ NA) %>%
      italicize_levels() %>%
      italicize_labels() %>%
      list()
  )

# stack tables
tbl <-
  tbl_stack(
    tbls = df_results$tbl,
    group_header = df_results$Country
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent Daniel. This suits me perfectly. But is there any further adjustment that can be made to "sort" the countries alphabetically. And still % digits =2?

I did implement the routine, but it was not successful.
BW

Comment: You can just arrange the tibble by country to get them in the order you prefer, and use the digits argument in tbl_svysummary to specify the digits of the percentage. You could also look into the remove_row_type to remove the repeated Gender row

Comment: Grat, I will try it on my return to work!

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I was able to adjust the decimal places in percent (digits = Gender ~ c(0,1)). I also managed to remove the repeating description "Gender" (remove_row_type(Gender, 
                      type = "header").

How could I include, at the end of the table, the summary (averages) for Gender (M and W)?

Comment: Use the same infrastructure you already have. Add a row to `df_results` that has overall results.

Comment: Sorry. I was unable to create these lines more in the final table when adding or getting the result (A, B, C) summarizing all countries (Overall) for gender (M and W). Please could you guide me where this command line would come in.

Comment: Append this one line tibble to `df_results`.

df_overall <-
  tibble(Country = "Overall") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    # subset the design object within each country
    design = df_survey %>% list(),
    # construct gtsummary table within each stratum
    tbl = 
      design %>%
      tbl_svysummary(by = Result,
                     percent = "row",
                     include = -Country) %>% 
      <...> %>% # removed to save space
      list()
  )

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to run the code. However, I executed it separately and generated two table objects (gtsummary objects). Then I stacked them with gtsummary::tbl_stack. How can I remove (100.0%) that is the result of the "add_overall" function?

Comment: Instead of using `add_overall()` you can merge a `tbl_summary()` table that just has Ns instead

Comment: Excellent, once again. I consider my questions answered. Colleagues will be able to read and adjust the code to their demands. In the end, have a table close to the publication format. This is the best thing about the gtsummary R package.